# How to pass variable data into .NET MAUI GraphicsView canvas

Tags: c#, graphics, .net-6.0, draw, maui

I am trying to render some lines on a .NET MAUI `GraphicsView`. The lines are stored as `Vector2` data in an array on my `MainPage`.

My problem is that I don't know how to pass variable data from the `MainPage` into the `Draw()` method of the `IDrawable` class. In the GraphicsViewDemos are a lot of examples but they load files from the app's ressources and they don't show how to pass data into it. My goal is to update the canvas in realtime.

Here is an example of a single hardcoded line from the demos:

```cs
internal class GraphicsDrawable: IDrawable
{
    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 6;
        canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 90, 100);
    }
}
```

In the Mainpage.xaml is following code:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <drawable:GraphicsDrawable x:Key="drawable" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

and

```xml
<GraphicsView Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
              HeightRequest="300"
              WidthRequest="400" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the array of Vector2 values via Binding:

**Drawable**

Create a `BindableProperty` as follows:

```cs
internal class GraphicsDrawable: IDrawable
{
    public Vector2[] Vectors
    {
       get => (Vector2[])GetValue(VectorsProperty);
       set => SetValue(VectorsProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty VectorsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Vectors), typeof(Vector2[]), typeof(GraphicsDrawable));

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 6;

        //Use vectors here
        canvas.DrawLine(Vectors[0].X, Vectors[0].Y, Vectors[1].X, Vectors[1].Y);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

Assuming you have your array defined as follows:

```cs
private Vector2[] _vectorArray;
public Vector2[] VectorArray
{
    get => _vectorArray;
    set
    {
        if(_vectorArray == value) return;
        _vectorArray = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**View**

In your view, you can now bind to the property:

```xml
<GraphicsView HeightRequest="300"
              WidthRequest="400">
    <GraphicsView.Drawable>
       <GraphicsDrawable Vectors="{Binding VectorArray}" />
    </GraphicsView.Drawable>
</GraphicsView>
```

Note: You cannot use your `GraphicsDrawable` as a `StaticResource`, because then the value changes won't be propagated. Also, using it as a resource generally shouldn't be necessary in your scenario.

This is just one way, an MVVM-way, to do it.