# Binding from view to GraphicsView property in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui, .net-maui

I am trying to add a slider, and a canvas to my MainPage.
Slider Value will control the height of the drawn shape. However, I am having an extremely hard time trying to bind the properties.

I am not sure how to bind to a resource class.

**My View**

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodel:MainViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <charts:CustomChart x:Key="drawable"></charts:CustomChart>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Slider 
                x:Name="Sldr"
                Minimum="0.3"
                Maximum="1.0"
                Value="{Binding Hayt}"
                WidthRequest="200"
                />

        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <GraphicsView>
            <GraphicsView.Drawable>
                <charts:CustomChart Grid_Height="{Binding Hayt}" />
            </GraphicsView.Drawable>
        </GraphicsView>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**My ViewModel**

```
    internal class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    double hayt;
    public double Hayt
    {
        get { return hayt; }
        set
        {
            if (hayt != value)
                hayt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Grapview Class**

```
internal class CustomChart : GraphicsView, IDrawable
{
    // Screen Parameters
    readonly float ScreenWidth = (float)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
    readonly float ScreenHeight = (float)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
    readonly float Density = (float)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;

    public double Grid_Height
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(Grid_Height_Adjuster);
        set => SetValue(Grid_Height_Adjuster, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty Grid_Height_Adjuster = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Grid_Height),typeof(double),typeof(CustomChart),0.7);

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {

        float Y_Top   = dirtyRect.Top;
        float Y_Bot   = dirtyRect.Bottom / Density * (float)Grid_Height;
        float X_Right = dirtyRect.Right / Density;
        float X_Left  = dirtyRect.Left;


    }
}
```

When I try,
[How to pass variable data into .net MAUI GraphicsView canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73997548/how-to-pass-variable-data-into-net-maui-graphicsview-canvas),
.Net is saying => No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Grid_Height", or mismatching type between value and property.

Comment: From the docs: The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous code：

```
    public double Grid_Height
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(Grid_Height_Adjuster);
        set => SetValue(Grid_Height_Adjuster, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty Grid_Height_Adjuster = BindableProperty.Create
          (nameof(Grid_Height),typeof(double),typeof(CustomChart),0.7);
```

Change to this:

```
    public double Grid_Height
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(Grid_HeightProperty);
        set => SetValue(Grid_HeightProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty Grid_HeightProperty = BindableProperty.Create
          (nameof(Grid_Height),typeof(double),typeof(CustomChart),0.7);
```

When you create a bindable property, you need to keep the naming format of
"PropertyName+`Property`". For more details, you can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties#create-a-property).