# In .NET MAUI, how do I pass variables to a GraphicsView.Drawable in a ContentView

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have the following collectionView in ProceduresPage.xaml (my questions is related to the view:ScoreGaugeView part and how to pass the score to my IDrawable in order to draw a needle gauge).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MediSkillApp.View.ProceduresPage"
             Title="Alle mine indgreb"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MediSkillApp.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:ProceduresViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MediSkillApp.Model"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MediSkillApp.View">

    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*"
          ColumnSpacing="5"
          RowSpacing="0">

        <CollectionView
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Procedures}"  
            RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding GetProceduresCommand}"
            RemainingItemsThreshold="5">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Procedure">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Frame Margin="5">
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="64,*, 64">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                                   HeightRequest="48"
                                   WidthRequest="48"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                <VerticalStackLayout
                                    Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ProcedureTypeString}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource Heading}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding OpRoleString}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource NormalLabel}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM-yyyy}'}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource NormalLabel}"/>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                                <view:ScoreGaugeView
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    ScoreValue="{Binding GetAvgScore}"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsScored}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </Grid>
       
</ContentPage>
```

It produces frames like these (an icon, some text, and a score if it has one):

[image]

Now, I want to add a scoregauge needle to show the score.

I also have the ScoreGaugeView (ScoreGaugeView.xaml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:drawables="clr-namespace:MediSkillApp.Drawables"
             x:Class="MediSkillApp.View.ScoreGaugeView">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable x:Key="scoreGaugeDrawable"/>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{TemplateBinding ScoreValue, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Image Source="scoremeter.png"/>

                <GraphicsView>
                    <GraphicsView.Drawable>
                        <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable/>
                    </GraphicsView.Drawable>
                </GraphicsView>

            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>
```

And my ScoreGaugeDrawable (ScoreGaugeDrawable.cs)

```cs
namespace MediSkillApp.Drawables;

public class ScoreGaugeDrawable : IDrawable
{    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect) {
        var centerPoint = new PointF(32, 0);
        var circleRadius = 5;

        canvas.FillColor = Colors.Black;
        canvas.FillCircle(centerPoint, circleRadius);
    }
}
```

So my question is how to pass the score to my `ScoreGaugeDrawable`, so I know where to point the needle?

EDIT:
I updated my ScoreGaugeView.xaml to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:drawables="clr-namespace:MediSkillApp.Drawables"
             x:Class="MediSkillApp.View.ScoreGaugeView">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding GetAvgScore, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Image Source="scoremeter.png"/>

        <GraphicsView>
            <GraphicsView.Drawable>
                <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable 
                    Score="{Binding AvgScore}"/>
            </GraphicsView.Drawable>
        </GraphicsView>

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

And the ScoreGaugeDrawable.cs to:

```
namespace MediSkillApp.Drawables;

public class ScoreGaugeDrawable : BindableObject, IDrawable
{
    private string score = "";
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScoreProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Score),
        typeof(double),
        typeof(ScoreGaugeDrawable));

    public double Score
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScoreProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScoreProperty, value);
    }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        var centerPoint = new PointF(32, 0);
        var circleRadius = 5;

        canvas.FillColor = Colors.Black;
        canvas.FillCircle(centerPoint, circleRadius);

        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Black;
        canvas.DrawLine(centerPoint, new Point(0, Score));
    }
}
```

This will print the number in the label but not pass the value to the drawable. In my Procedure class I have:

```
    public double AvgScore { get; set; }

    public string GetAvgScore {
        get {
            if (AvgScore == 0) return "";
            return AvgScore.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variable data into .net MAUI GraphicsView canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73997548/how-to-pass-variable-data-into-net-maui-graphicsview-canvas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a [BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties). You can add that to your `ScoreGaugeDrawable` class and then pass the value to it from the XAML, e.g. using a Binding expression.

Update your `ScoreGaugeDrawable` like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

public class ScoreGaugeDrawable : BindableObject, IDrawable
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScoreProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Score), typeof(double), typeof(ScoreGaugeDrawable));

    public double Score
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScoreProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScoreProperty, value);
    }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect) 
    {
        var centerPoint = new PointF(32, 0);
        var circleRadius = 5;

        canvas.FillColor = Colors.Black;
        canvas.FillCircle(centerPoint, circleRadius);

        //Add your drawing logic that uses the Score property 
        //...
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to pass a value to the `ScoreGaugeDrawable` like this, e.g. by Binding to another property that holds the score value:

```xml
<GraphicsView>
    <GraphicsView.Drawable>
        <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable Score="{Binding SomeScore}"/>
    </GraphicsView.Drawable>
</GraphicsView>
```

Let me know if this works, because I've seen issues with Bindings and Drawables before.

By the way, you can safely remove this from your XAML, since that's not used anywhere:

```xml
<ContentView.Resources>
    <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable x:Key="scoreGaugeDrawable"/>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

Something that I also noticed is that you're using a `ControlTemplate`, but for no apparent reason. It should be possible to remove that and place the `VerticalStackLayout` directly into the `ContentView`.

Comment: I did try that solution before posting, but could not get it to work. For some reason I cannot figure out it tells me that "The name 'BindablePropery' does not exist in the current context" and same with GetValue and SetValue.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer. Fixed that. You might also need to add the `using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;` directive manually to your *.cs* file. You should add the things you've tried to your question.

Comment: I have the Microsoft.Maui.Controls in my globalusings. But I still get the "Error CS0103 The name 'GetValue' does not exist in the current context" and same for SetValue.

Comment: Ah, yes, makes sense, because you don't have any base class that provides those. You'll need to inherit from `BindableObject` for that. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Then I get a new error
"System.InvalidOperationException
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."
During ScoreGaugeView.xaml.cs : 
public ScoreGaugeView()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
}

Comment: I don't know what else you're currently doing in your code. This should work AFAIK. Did you only use my code or did you already add other functionality to the `ScoreGaugeDrawable` class?

Comment: I must have done something to screw up my project. I tested your solution in a new project and it worked without problems. When I removed the ControlTemplate as you suggested it almost works. I can pass it some fixed value and it will use that, but I cannot get the binding to pass it a value to work.

Comment: For me, I found that whenever the bound value changes, I needed to make sure I also Invalidate the GraphicsView to cause the Drawable to react to the changes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the suggestions for this question did not work in my case. I was able to get this to work by using the code behind instead of the XAML binding.

**Maui version I am on at time of this answer:** 8.0.0-preview.4.8333

**Solution:**

In the XAML page:

```
<GraphicsView x:Name="myGraphicsView"/>
```

In the code behind of above XAML page:

```
string myStringToPass = "test";
MyDrawable d = new MyDrawable();
d.myString = myStringToPass;
myGraphicsView.Drawable = d;
```

In your drawable class:

```
public string myString;

public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
{
     // do something with myString
}
```

You can remove these from your code:

```
<ContentView.Resources>
     <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable x:Key="scoreGaugeDrawable"/>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

```
<GraphicsView.Drawable>
     <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable Score="{Binding AvgScore}"/>
</GraphicsView.Drawable>
```

Comment: It turned out that for some reason, Drawables cannot be used with BindableProperty. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020765/net-maui-binding-to-graphicsview

Comment: @KnightofniDK 

Answer (score 0):

A solution is you can build a custom `GraphicsView` that also implements `IDrawable` (i.e. `Drawable = this`). All properties of your custom `GraphicsView` will automatically be properties of your `IDrawable`. In addition to sharing properties, we can also make sure that property changes cause `Invalidate` to be invoked on the `GraphicsView`. In our `IDrawable` we also have access to the `GraphicsView`'s `Width` and `Height`.

```cs
// GaugeView.cs
public class GaugeView: GraphicsView, IDrawable
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MinimumProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Minimum), typeof(double), typeof(GaugeView), 0.0, propertyChanged: RequestInvalidate);
    public static readonly BindableProperty MaximumProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Maximum), typeof(double), typeof(GaugeView), 100.0, propertyChanged: RequestInvalidate);
    public static readonly BindableProperty ValueProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value), typeof(double), typeof(GaugeView), propertyChanged: RequestInvalidate);
    public static readonly BindableProperty GaugeColorProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(GaugeColor), typeof(Color), typeof(GaugeView), Colors.SteelBlue, propertyChanged: RequestInvalidate);
    public static readonly BindableProperty GaugeSizeProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(GaugeSize), typeof(float), typeof(GaugeView), 10.0f, propertyChanged: RequestInvalidate);
    public double Minimum
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty);
        set => SetValue(MinimumProperty, value);
    }
    public double Maximum
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty);
        set => SetValue(MaximumProperty, value);
    }
    public double Value
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }
    public Color GaugeColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(GaugeColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(GaugeColorProperty, value);
    }
    public float GaugeSize
    {
        get => (float)GetValue(GaugeSizeProperty);
        set => SetValue(GaugeSizeProperty, value);
    }
    private static void RequestInvalidate(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (bindable is GraphicsView)
        {
            ((GraphicsView)bindable).Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public GaugeView()
    {
        Drawable = this;
    }
    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        double NormalizedValue = (Math.Clamp(Value, Minimum, Maximum) - Minimum) / (Maximum - Minimum);
        canvas.StrokeColor = GaugeColor;
        canvas.StrokeSize = GaugeSize;
        canvas.DrawArc(10f, 10f, (float)Width - 20f, (float)Height - 20f, 240f, 240f - (float) NormalizedValue * 300f, true, false);
    }
}
```

In XAML, we can bind directly to the custom `GraphicsView` knowing that our properties will make its way to the `IDrawable`:

```xml
<Slider
    x:Name="slider"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="5"
    Value="4.43" />
<local:GaugeView
    x:Name="gaugeView"
    BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"
    WidthRequest="200"
    HeightRequest="200"
    GaugeColor="Red"
    GaugeSize="10"
    Minimum="{Binding Minimum}"
    Maximum="{Binding Maximum}"
    Value="{Binding Value}" />
```