# .NET MAUI binding to GraphicsView

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui

I have problems understanding how binding works in .NET MAUI. My goal is to have two ways of displaying a score inside a CollectionView, a label with the number and a graphical representation. The binding of the score to the label works just fine, but the binding to the Drawable does not. If I write a number instead of using a binding, it is passed just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

ProceduresPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MediSkillApp.Model"
             xmlns:drawables="clr-namespace:MediSkillApp.Drawables"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MediSkillApp.ViewModel"
             x:Class="MediSkillApp.View.ProceduresPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:ProceduresViewModel"
             Title="Alle mine indgreb">

    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*"
          ColumnSpacing="5"
          RowSpacing="0">

        <CollectionView
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Procedures}"
            RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding GetProceduresCommand}"
            RemainingItemsThreshold="5">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Procedure">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Frame Margin="5">
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="64,*, 64">
                                <Image 
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Source="{Binding Icon}"
                                    HeightRequest="48"
                                    WidthRequest="48"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                
                                <VerticalStackLayout
                                    Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ProcedureTypeString}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource Heading}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding OpRoleString}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource NormalLabel}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM-yyyy}'}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource NormalLabel}"/>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                                
                                <VerticalStackLayout
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsScored}">

                                    <!-- this binding works -->
                                    <Label Text="{Binding AvgScore, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                                    <Image Source="scoremeter.png"/>
                                    
                                    <GraphicsView>
                                        <GraphicsView.Drawable>

                                            <!-- this binding does not -->
                                            <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable
                                                    Score="{Binding AvgScore}"/>
                                        </GraphicsView.Drawable>
                                    </GraphicsView>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </Grid>
    
    
</ContentPage>
```

ScoreGaugeDrawable.cs

```cs
namespace MediSkillApp.Drawables;

public class ScoreGaugeDrawable : BindableObject, IDrawable
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScoreProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Score),
        typeof(double),
        typeof(ScoreGaugeDrawable));

    public double Score {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScoreProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScoreProperty, value);
    }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        var centerPoint = new PointF(32, 0);
        var circleRadius = 5;

        canvas.FillColor = Colors.Black;
        canvas.FillCircle(centerPoint, circleRadius);

        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Black;
        canvas.DrawLine(centerPoint, new Point(0, Score * 10)); //Just draw something for testing
    }
}
```

Procedure.cs

```cs
namespace MediSkillApp.Model;

public class Procedure
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string GetDate {
        get => Date.ToString("d/M-yyyy");
    }

    public int ProcedureType { get; set; }
    public string ProcedureTypeString { get; set; }
    public double AvgScore { get; set; }

    public string GetAvgScore {
        get {
            if (AvgScore == 0) return "";
            return AvgScore.ToString();
        }
    }

    public int OpRole { get; set; }
    public string OpRoleString { get; set; }

    public string Icon {
        get {
            switch (ProcedureType) {
                case 7:
                    return Icons.IconBleed;
                case 8:
                    return Icons.IconTEA;
                case 18:
                    return Icons.IconTEA;
                default:
                    return Icons.IconSurgery;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsScored => AvgScore > 0;
}
```

ProceduresViewModel.cs

```cs
using MediSkillApp.Model;
using MediSkillApp.Services;

namespace MediSkillApp.ViewModel;

public partial class ProceduresViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Procedure> Procedures { get; } = new();
    private APIService APIservice;

    public ProceduresViewModel(APIService aPIservice) {
        APIservice = aPIservice;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task GetProceduresAsync() {
        if(IsBusy) return;

        try {
            IsBusy = true;
            var procedures = await APIservice.GetProceduresAsync("8", "dawda", Procedures.Count, 15);

            foreach (Procedure procedure in procedures) {
                Procedures.Add(procedure);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        } finally {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public void ClearProcedures() {
        Procedures.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `AvgScore` property defined? I assume it's in the `ProceduresViewModel`. You should show the relevant bits of that ViewModel.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the `Draw()` method to see how often it's called and what the value of `Score` is?

Comment: I have updated with the ViewModel and the Procedure model. When I put a breakpoint in Draw, it is only called when I would expect, i.e. when IsScored is true (defined in Procedure.cs) but the value is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem. It seems that *Drawables* cannot be used with `BindableProperty`, at least it doesn't have any effect, the value of the property doesn't get updated.

I managed to find a workaround for this issue, however. Instead of adding the `Score` property to the `ScoreGaugeDrawable`, you can add it to the `GraphicsView` by extending it via inheritance.

You can remove the `BindableObject` base class as well as the bindable `ScoreProperty` from the `ScoreGaugeDrawable` and turn the `Score` property into a regular property with default getter and setter:

```cs
namespace MediSkillApp.Drawables;

public class ScoreGaugeDrawable : IDrawable
{
    public double Score { get; set; }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        var centerPoint = new PointF(32, 0);
        var circleRadius = 5;

        canvas.FillColor = Colors.Black;
        canvas.FillCircle(centerPoint, circleRadius);

        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Black;
        canvas.DrawLine(centerPoint, new Point(0, Score * 10)); //Just draw something for testing
    }
}
```

Then, create a `ScoreGraphicsView` that inherits from `GraphicsView` and add the bindable `ScoreProperty` to it:

```cs
namespace MediSkillApp.Drawables;

public class ScoreGraphicsView : GraphicsView
{
    public double Score
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScoreProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScoreProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ScoreProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Score), typeof(double), typeof(ScoreGraphicsView), propertyChanged: ScorePropertyChanged);

    private static void ScorePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (bindable is not ScoreGraphicsView { Drawable: ScoreGaugeDrawable drawable } view)
        {
            return;
        }

        drawable.Score = (double)newValue;
        view.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

This way, the score needs to be passed to the GraphicsView, which (unfortunately) must now know about the `ScoreGaugeDrawable`. What this code does is, it receives any updates to the bindable `ScoreProperty` and relays the value to the `ScoreGaugeDrawable`. If the value has changed and the `Drawable` is of type `ScoreGaugeDrawable`, the new value is set and then the view gets invalidated, which triggers a redraw.

You can use the `ScoreGraphicsView` and `ScoreGaugeDrawable` like this in your XAML then:

```xml
<drawables:ScoreGraphicsView
    Score="{Binding AvgScore}">
    <drawables:ScoreGraphicsView.Drawable>
        <drawables:ScoreGaugeDrawable/>
    </drawables:ScoreGraphicsView.Drawable>
</drawables:ScoreGraphicsView>
```

This is not ideal, but should solve your problem for the time being. I've tested this myself in my [MAUI Samples](https://github.com/ewerspej/maui-samples) repository and it works quite well.

Comment: ewerspej, you are a genius! Thank you very much, I was close to going mad and you made my day. By the way, there are a few typos in your answer (RadiusProperty should be ScoreProperty in 'set', and ScoreDrawable should be ScoreGaugeDrawable in order to fit in with the original naming).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. That happened, because I tried the solution myself and then copied it to the answer before adjusting the names.

Comment: Hey, thank you for letting me know. You are right. I removed that comment to remove confusion.